# Most efficient regular expression for Nginx location

Tags: regex, nginx, webserver

What is the most efficient way to define a location directive which matches something like

```
location = /[0-9a-zA-Z_-]{1,6} { content_by_lua_file ....}
```

In other words a URI which matches a string from 1 to 6 characters with "-", "_", digits and letters.

Or is it faster to check string length within my LUA code, which will generate the output by using a location directive like

```
location  / {content_by_lua_file...}
```

Answer (score 10):

Regular expressions are very efficient at what they do.

When the task is trivial (for instance checking the presence of a particular string), a string function can be faster than a regex—depending on the platform. Here, you are checking both for a character range and a length. It's unlikely that Lua code (compiled at run time) will be faster than the pre-compiled C code of the PCRE regex library used by nginx.

In general, the regex for `a string from 1 to 6 characters with "-", "_", digits and letters` can be written as

```
^[-\w]{1,6}$
```

That is because

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The `\w` word character matches letters, digits and the underscore character
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

However, in nginx, the `~` (request starts with) operator allows us to drop the beginning anchor `^`. You would write something like this:

```
location ~ [-\w]{1,6}$ {
    # some rewrite code, for example
    # rewrite ^([^/]+)/?$ /oldsite/$1 break;
}
```

One more morsel of information for the curious: in Lua itself, the above regex could be turned into a Lua pattern, where `%` is used in place of `\` to form metacharacters:

```
^[-%w]{1,6}$
```

**Reference**

- [ngx_http_rewrite_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)
- [Lua Patterns](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html)

Comment: this is the answer I'd have written +1

Answer (score 1):

I think that in Lua you will have to check not only length, but also the content of string.
Nginx uses the C library PCRE for regular expressions.
There is also PCRE-JIT which JIT compiles regular expression, particularly useful if the regular expression is more complex than the one in your question.
I think in Nginx it's faster.